# SailsJS + Waterline concurrent db requests with promises

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, concurrency, sails.js, waterline

I'm a bit confused about concurrency in SailsJS's waterline.
Currently I'm doing data retrieval like this;

```
var results = {};

// Get user by id 5
User.find('5', function(err, user) {
  results.user = user;

  // when it resolves, get messages
  Message.find({userId: '5'}, function(err, messages) {
    results.messages = messages;

    // when message query resolves, get other stuff
    OtherStuff.find({userId: '5'}, function(err, otherStuff) {
      results.otherStuff = otherStuff;

      res.view({results});      
    });
  });
});
```

The problem is that the DB calls are not concurrent. Every request launches after previous one's promise has been fulfilled. I'd like to launch all requests at the same time and then see somehow if all promises are fulfilled and if so, proceed to pass results to the view.

How am I gonna achieve this concurrency with db requests?

Thanks!

Comment: You are not even using promises?

Answer (score 4):

Use `async.auto`.  The `async` module is globalized in Sails:

```
async.auto({

    user: function(cb) {
        // Note--use findOne here, not find!  "find" doesn't accept
        // an ID argument, only an object.
        User.findOne('5').exec(cb);
    },
    messages: function(cb) {
        Message.find({userId: '5'}).exec(cb);
    },
    otherStuff: function(cb) {
        OtherStuff.find({userId: '5'}).exec(cb);
    }

},

    // This will be called when all queries are complete, or immediately
    // if any of them returns an error
    function allDone (err, results) {

        // If any of the queries returns an error,
        // it'll populate the "err" var
        if (err) {return res.serverError(err);}

        // Otherwise "results" will be an object whose keys are
        // "user", "messages" and "otherStuff", and whose values
        // are the results of those queries
        res.view(results);

    }
);
```

Comment: This is really cool - works like a charm! Thanks for the answer